# Case in where clause sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have `@Original` table which have 6 records from 1 to 6,

1. I want that if my @temp table have any record then return the matching record with my `@Original` table
2. other wise return all the record from @Original table

and I have to do with multiple @Temp table with my one @original table with different column

```
DECLARE @Temp table
(
   SearchId int
) 

insert into @Temp(SearchId)
select 1
 union
select 2

DECLARE @Original table
(
    BalanceId int
)

insert into @Original(BalanceId)
select 1
 union
select 2
 union
select 3
 union
select 4
 union
select 5
 union
select 6

select * 
from @Original b
where BalanceID in 
       (case 
           when not exists(select COUNT(1) from @Temp) then BalanceId
           ELSE (select SearchId From @Temp t where t.SearchId = b.BalanceID)
end)
```

Currently I am only getting either the matching record, but when I empty my `@Temp` table then it returns no rows

Comment: `CASE` in T-SQL is an **expression** - it can return one of several literal values - but it **CANNOT** be used to execute code like a `SELECT` statement. You'll have to rethink your code and rewrite it

Comment: Can you please help me to write it in proper way, as i have multiple temp table which might have data or not, and as i know this is the only simplest way to get the record based on temp table data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
DECLARE @Temp table
(
   SearchId int
) 

/*
insert into @Temp(SearchId)
select 1
 union
select 2
*/
DECLARE @Original table
(
    BalanceId int
)

insert into @Original(BalanceId)
select 1
 union
select 2
 union
select 3
 union
select 4
 union
select 5
 union
select 6

select * 
from @Original b
where BalanceID in 
       (case 
           when not exists(select * from @Temp) then BalanceId
           ELSE (select SearchId From @Temp t where t.SearchId = b.BalanceID)
end)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this would be cleaner putting the conditional outside rather then in the where clause.

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM @Temp) 
  SELECT * 
    FROM @Original b 
   WHERE EXISTS(SELECT SearchId FROM @Temp t WHERE t.SearchId = b.BalanceID)
ELSE
  SELECT * 
    FROM @Original
```